How to add inward curve at both sides to triangle build using css
I am building an application where there is a triangle image direction upward and have inward curve at left and right side in white color. I am constructing it via css. I have build the triangle but unable to add inward curve to it.

Below is my html code
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>template</title> 

     <style type="text/css"> 
        table{ 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
} 
.triangle { 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 3; 
    top: 3px; 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
    border-style: solid; 
    border-width: 0 30px 30px 30px; 
    border-color: transparent transparent #FFFFFF transparent; 
    transform: rotate(0deg);  

} 

.inner-body { 
    padding:10px; 
} 
     </style> 


</head> 
<body> 
    <table width="100%"> 
        <tr> 
            <td height="100px"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td align="center" valign="top"> 
                <table width="100%"> 
                    <tr> 
                        <td width="2%"></td> 
                        <td class="gradient-bg"> 
                            <table width="100%"> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td class="inner-body"></td> 
                                </tr> 
                                <tr> 
                                    <td align="center"> 
                                        <div class="triangle"></div> 
                                    </td> 
                                </tr> 
                            </table> 
                        </td> 
                        <td width="2%"></td> 
                    </tr> 
                </table> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td align="center" valign="middle" height="100px"> 
                <!--<img src="Images/logo.JPG" width="90" />--> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 

</body> 
</html>

As shown in image, the white triangle is having inward curve at both sides. I want to add those curve. How should I do this?
Difference with other question
In my question I need to apply curve effect on triangle object and the solution that have been provided in other question is for rectangular object. The effect is applied to one side only. As you can see image I have attached, need to apply curve effect at both side of triangle. Also I didn't have deep knowledge regarding CSS therefore I have posted question in this forum.

This question is similar to: CSS transparent curved shape with two rounded sides. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The duplicate might not seem related at first look, but the technique is the very same. It can be solved with radial-rgadient, clip-path, psudeo-elements, svg...

you have a rectangular element aswell. Nothing in your code makes it triangular. It simply is just rotated. With the duplicate methods you don't even need to rotate it.

I'd just use a clip-path, to be honest :)


.c {
  background: #cc512a;
  aspect-ratio: 14 / 6;
  clip-path: padding-box path('M0,0 L0,60 C30,60 57,38 70,0C83,38 100,60 140,60L140,0L0,0Z');
}
<div class="c">This is some content</div>



